# Adding cell values based on string in next cell

Tags: excel

Ok, I´ve a row with values and some variable words, ie:

July: 34 - sweaters - 123 - shirts - 12 - trousers - 90 - sweaters

(each "-" means a different cell").

Now, I would need to add all the sweaters and shirts, etc for the month so I would need to sum 34+90 because those are the sweaters, then 123 + the next value for shirts, etc.

How should I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts in row B and you've got the values you're adding in J1:L1, enter this [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) in J2:L2 using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> and copy down for as many rows as necessary.

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$H$2=J$1,$A$2:$G$2))
```

[image]

Better yet, organize your data in a way that makes sense (to a computer), with the months in one column, the categories in the next column and the values in a 3rd. You can then use functions like `SUMIF` or a pivot table. In the long run that's the only way to go. This way is too hard to maintain and error-prone.

EDIT: maybeWeCouldStealAVan's solution is better than mine, as it's not an array formula:
`=SUMIFS($A$2:$G$2,$B$2:$H$2,J$1)`

Comment: +1 for the shifted ranges and for suggesting a refactoring.  Alternatively, you could use SUMIFS or SUMIF (For consistency, I prefer to use SUMIFS regardless of the number of conditions): `=SUMIFS($A$2:$G$2,$B$2:$H$2,J$1)`

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan, yours is clearly preferable, as it avoids array formulas. I have this mental block against using `SUMIF`, etc., for non-columnar arrays, even though I'll think to use `SUM(IF` to do the exact same thing. Maybe this will cure it :). Anyways, I edited my answer to recommend your formula.